# Jaws 13 + IE 11: file input reading is weird

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have a screen where everything is fine until I encounter a file input.
I am aware the way that IE rendered the file input makes it two tab stops but for some reason on the first stop Jaws insists on reading the label of the previous field.

1. Jaws is reading `My Field Edit type in text`.
2. I then tab to the input and get `My Field Edit`.
3. I then tab again and get `star mandatory My File Upload to activate press space bar`.

I have tried various combinations of grouping `aria-labelledby` and `aria-describedby` but cannot get it to behave differently.

Any suggestions?

This is the chunk of HTML:

```html
<!-- previous field -->
                  <div id="nodeW137" role="group">
                   <div >
                    <label for="nodeW137-MyField" >
                     <span >My Field</span>
                    </label>
                   </div>
                   <input class="tabindexSet" tabindex="131" name="nodeW137-MyField" id="nodeW137-MyField" maxlength="20" type="text">
                  </div>
                  <div id="nodeW138">
                   <div >
                    <div id="nodeW139">
                     <div >
                      <div id="nodeW141">
                       <div>
                        <div id="nodeW143-wrapper" role="group">
<!-- wanting this to be read -->
                          <div>
                           <label for="nodeW143">
                            <span aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">*</span>
                            <span >Mandatory</span>
                            <span >My File Upload</span>
                           </label>
                          </div>
<!-- input is here -->
                         <div>
                          <span id="nodeW143-span" role="link">Upload</span>
                          <input tabindex="132" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" id="nodeW143" name="nodeW143" type="file">
                         </div>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                      </div>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: You may be better off just leaving it the way it is. I tested with Jaws 15, IE 11, and Firefox 31 and got the same behavior in both browsers. This at least rules out it being an issue with Jaws 13 not officially supporting IE 11 since Jaws 13 was released two years ago and IE 11 was released 9 months ago.

Comment: Solution was to remove tab stop from input and put it on the span. Thanks for your help.